# Hired with H1-B before April & Starting in October - How is this possible?

Tags: usa, working-visas

I have not understood yet the following with regards to H1-B visas.

As far as I understand, you have to be hired by a company in the US before April because in April the lottery for the visas is taking place.

But you can only start your job with your visa in October.

How is it possible that a company will be waiting for you for six months?

Most companies in London want you to start at most in one month after you are hired.

Answer (score 3):

The lottery is for visas in the following year. The federal government is on an October-to-September cycle, so the visas can't actually be issued until the following October.

Employers who work with the system know that this is just one of the things about the system they have to deal with.  If they need someone more promptly than that, they'll just have to hire someone who is already authorized to work in the the US, or they'll have to hire someone in an office outside the US.